# CakeBake gerando Controller inválido

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3

Estou gerando um controller pelo cakebake baseado numa tabela chamada `cliente_planos`.
Ele gera os métodos do controller utilizando sempre `$this->ClientePlanos`, está gerando corretamente, mas nenhum método do controle funciona e descobri que eles só funcionam se eu alterar para `$this->Clienteplanos`.

O correto é `$this->ClientePlanos`, mas não sei onde configurar o bake pra ele transformar a tabela `cliente_planos` em `$this->ClientePlanos` sem dar erro de objeto não encontrado.

estou utilizando cakephp 3 e PHP 5.6.3

Comment: Trabalho com o cake à 4 anos, desde que comecei a trabalhar com nomenclaturas em inglês tem sido muito melhor. Se puder, faça o mesmo, sua produtividade vai aumentar ainda mais.

Answer (score 1):

Esse é um problema causado pelas diferenças entre a nossa lingua e o inglês.

No CakePHP quem faz essa mágica de dar os nomes automaticamente é a biblioteca Inflector (http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/pt/core-libraries/inflector.html), ela possuí as regras internas que funcionam muito bem para a lingua inglesa, mas você terá esse tipo de problema quando usar alguns termos em português, existem algumas saídas, são elas:

1 - trabalhar nomenclatura de tabelas em inglês (isso é como manda as convenções do CakePHP)

2 - instanciar manualmente o modelo na variável que desejar (ex: $ClientePlanos), podendo inclusive usar uma propriedade como $this->ClientePlanos.

3 - criar conjunto de regras do idioma Português para o Inflector e injetar no Cake, assim você poderá usar as convenções sem ter problemas desse tipo.

Um forte abraço

Comment: cara nao tem como vc marcar minha pergunta?
não consigo fazer nada porque não tenho reputação suficiente, não consigo nem marcar respostas que tive como corretas.

obrigado